# 最後に「か」が置かれると疑問文になるかどうか

Tags: academic-japanese

## Japanese

今日、他の教員の書いたものを読んでいたら、以下のような本のタイトルが出てきました：

> Z: AがいかにBに影響を及ぼしCを形成してきたか

元となった本は英語だったのですが、英語のタイトルは：

> Z: How A influences B and forms C.

英語の場合、「How」は疑問の意味以外に、手段を説明する「[ように](http://ejje.weblio.jp/content/how)」の意味もあります。今回の場合の「How」は、その「ように」を意味する関係詞だと思います。例えば、

> Spaghetti: How I fill my stomach.

(スパゲティ：お腹いっぱいのなり方)

同じように、最後に「か」を置く文法は日本語に存在しているでしょうか。

私の質問はその最後の「か」についてなのですが、これは疑問の意味になりますか。また、別の意味を表す「か」になりうるのですか。例えば、「Xはこのようにできた」また「どんな手段を使っていた」の意味の「か」が存在しているのか。もしそうであれば、その文法を説明していただけませんか。

## English

Today I was reading something another faculty member wrote, and the following title appeared:

> Z: AがいかにBに影響を及ぼしCを形成してきたか

The original book is in English, and the English title is:

> Z: How A influences B and forms C.

In English, "how" can be used both to ask [a question and to explain means](http://ejje.weblio.jp/content/how). In the case of this title, I take it to be the means meaning [as a conjunction](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/how?s=t). For instance,

> Spaghetti: How I fill my stomach.

(Spaghetti: the way I get full)

Is there a 「か」 that can be place at the end that has this same meaning?

My question is about this final 「か」. Does the title become a question by having it there? Or does this 「か」 express something else. For instance, is there a　(final) 「か」 that means "this is how (preceding part) was done" or "these are the means that accomplish (preceding part)" ? If there is one, could someone explain the grammar. (preferably you would explain it in Japanese but obviously I'll take what I can get)

Comment: すみません、『表現全体を「手段」の意味に近くする』のところの意味がわかりません・・・『"How"が「どんな手段を使って」って意味になると』、ってことでしょうか・・・

Comment: @chocoさん、すみません。私のせいでした。とりあえず、もう一回日本語に頑張りますが、夕ご飯を食べ終わるところで、英語の文も加えます。

Comment: とりあえず、ここ(http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/34861/meaning/m0u/)に探していたのですが、私がわかる限りに当てはまる意味は見つけませんでした。

Comment: @choco いつも直してくれていることにありがたいです！

Answer (score 5, accepted):

「疑問詞 + ～～か」の形で、疑問ではなく手段、方法、過程などを表すことができます。

「いかに」「いかにして」は、「どうやって」「どのようにして」の堅い言い方で、「どんな方法・手段・やり方で」「どんな過程で」などの意味があります。

そして、「いかに～するか」「どうやって～するか」は、「どんな方法・過程で～するか」(in what way/process XX does ~~) や「～～する方法・手段・過程」(the way XX does ~~; the means XX does ~~ by; the process XX does ~~ in) という意味で使うことができます。

例えば、「この問題の[解]{と}き方」は、「どうやって/どのようにしてこの問題を解くか」や「この問題を解く方法」と同じ意味で、手段・方法を表します。「どうやって/どのようにしてこの問題を解いたか」と言うと、解いた過程を表して、「この問題を解いた過程」という感じがします。

（また、「いかに」には、「どれほど」「どの程度」(to what extent) の意味もあります。例えば、「AがいかにBに影響を及ぼしたか」は「AがBにどれほどの影響を及ぼしたか」「AがBに及ぼした影響の程度・大きさ」という意味と捉えることもできます。）

題名の「AがいかにBに影響を及ぼしCを形成してきたか」は、

> 「Aが**どのような方法で**Bに影響を及ぼしCを形成してきたか」
>   「AがBに影響を及ぼしてCを形成してきた(その)**方法**」
>   「Aが**どのような過程をたどって**Bに影響を及ぼしCを形成してきたか」
>   「AがBに影響を及ぼしCを形成してきた(その)**過程**」

などの意味に捉えられると思います。でも、学術論文の題名としては「どんな方法で」「どんなやり方で」よりも文語的な「いかに」を使った方がいいでしょうし、「～のやり方」「～してきた方法」という題名もちょっとカッコ悪いです。そういうわけで、英語の題名の「How A does ~~」に近い形で、日本語の題名が「Aがいかに～してきたか」になったのだと思います。

Comment: 答えしてくれてありがとうございます。いい勉強になっています。

Answer (score 2):

既に意味や用法についての詳しい回答がありますので蛇足かもしれませんが、この種の「か」が「別の意味を表せるか」という点、またその文法的役割についてお答えしたいと思います。

端的に申しますと、この種の「か」は、単独では「How」のような意味を表すことはできません。

例えば、質問文にある例でいいますと、

> AがいかにBに影響を及ぼしCを形成してきたか

という日本語のタイトルは、原文では、

> How A influences B and forms C

と表現されているとのことですが、ここで「How」を本質的に意味している日本語は「いかに」という語です。ですから、この「いかに」という語を省略すると、文の意味が変わってしまいます。

試しに、上述の例から「いかに」を抜いてみます。

> AがBに影響を及ぼしCを形成してきたか

日本語を母語とする大多数の人はこの文を、英語でいうところの

> Whether A influences B and forms C

という意味でとらえます。文中に「いかに」またはその類語がない状態では、「How」の意味する「どのように」「どのような手段で」等は表せません。

疑問詞とペアになっていない単独の「か」は、「whether」のような「不確定」または「別の可能性もあること」などの意味を表現することはできます。ですが、「How」のような意味を表すには「いかに」等の疑問詞と組み合わせて「か」を用いる必要があります。

この種の「か」は副助詞です。

副助詞「か」を付けることで、一連の語が名詞節としてまとまります。名詞のように使えるようになるということです。

例えば、以下の文はどちらも、「体言＋格助詞（を）＋用言」という構成です。

> **道**を尋ねる。
>
> **いつ彼が東京を訪れたか**を尋ねる。

「道」は名詞で、「いつ彼が東京を訪れたか」は名詞節です。このように名詞節は、文中の名詞の入る位置に自然に入れることができます。

副助詞「か」を用いると、名詞のような印象で疑問を提示できるということです。副助詞「か」は、意味を伝えるだけでなく、形といいますか、その文の在り方を伝える役割も果たしているといえます。

以上のことから、まとめますと、副助詞「か」は「How」の意味を単独で表現することはできませんが、「名詞節をつくる役割を果たす」という点においては「How」に近いものがあるといえるかもしれません。